# Mark duplicated values with their times of duplication

Tags: r

I am working with a data with duplicated values, and I want to get the time a duplicated value appears.

For example, if I have:

```
test_list <- c(0,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,7)
```

And I applied duplicated function `dups <- duplicated(test_list)`, we have `dups`:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[9]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

And for this `dups` I want to mark `TRUE` sequence with index to denote which time is this value duplicated. For example I would like to have eventually:

```
[1] 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 3
```

Could you guys give me some hints on how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can do a group by operation with `ave` to get the sequence and then subtract 1 from it

```
ave(test_list, test_list, FUN = seq_along)-1
#[1] 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I think there must be a better way to do this using `cumsum()` or something like that.  But this works with your example.

```
test_list <- c(0,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,7)
dups <- duplicated(test_list)

adding.it <- 0
dup.func <- function(x){
  if(x == FALSE){
    adding.it <<- 0
    return(0)
  }else{
    adding.it <<- adding.it + 1
    return(adding.it)
  }
}

result <- sapply(dups, dup.func)
result
#[1] 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 3
```